# How to use vue-virtual-scroll-list in Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```js
< script >
  export default {
    name: 'App',
    data() {
      return {
        items: [{
            price: '1',
            name: 'mm'
          },
          {
            price: '22',
            name: 'aa'
          },
          {
            price: '55',
            name: 'dd'
          },
          {
            price: '77',
            name: 'gg'
          },
          {
            price: '123',
            name: 'kk'
          },
          {
            price: '53',
            name: 'mn'
          },
          {
            price: '11',
            name: 'mm'
          },
          {
            price: '22',
            name: 'a'
          },
          {
            price: '33',
            name: 'd'
          },
          {
            price: '77',
            name: 'g'
          },
          {
            price: '1283',
            name: 'k'
          },
          {
            price: '589',
            name: 'n'
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  } <
  /script>
```

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <virtual-list
        class="list"
        style="height: 360px; overflow-y: auto"
        :data-key="'item'"
        :data-sources="item"
        :data-component="item"
        :estimate-size="3"
      />
      <div class="item" v-for="item in items" :key="item">
        <div class="id">{{ item.price }} {{ item.name }}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

I am trying to achieve virtual scroll in vuejs, I am able to render list in ui also, But unable to render them in virtual scroll. as shown in the image.

I am trying to achieve virtual scroll in vuejs, I am able to render list in ui also, But unable to render them in virtual scroll. as shown in the image.

tried installing :- npm install vue-virtual-scroll-list --save

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create vue component for `data-component` prop like below:

**Item.vue**

```js
<template>
  <div class="item">
    <span>{{ index }} - {{ source.name }}</span>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    index: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0
    },
    source: {
      type: Object,
      default() {
        return {}
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style  lang="scss" scoped>
.item {
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
}
</style>
```

And then use it in `virtual-list`

**App.vue**

```js
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <virtual-list
        class="list"
        style="height: 360px; overflow-y: auto"
        data-key="key"
        :keeps="20"
        :data-sources="computedItems"
        :data-component="Item"
      />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Item from './Item'
export default {
  name: 'App',
  data() {
    return {
      Item,
      items: [
        { price: '1', name: 'mm' },
        { price: '22', name: 'aa' },
        { price: '55', name: 'dd' },
        { price: '77', name: 'gg' },
        { price: '123', name: 'kk' },
        { price: '53', name: 'mn' },
        { price: '11', name: 'mm' },
        { price: '22', name: 'a' },
        { price: '33', name: 'd' },
        { price: '77', name: 'g' },
        { price: '1283', name: 'k' },
        { price: '589', name: 'n' }
      ]
    }
  },
  computed: {
    computedItems() {
      return this.items.map((item, index) => {
        item.key = `item_${index}`
        return item
      })
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

If you don't have unique key for each item, create an computed method to add it like in example.

Here is [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/live-demo-virtual-list-forked-rjrmv?file=/src/App.vue)

Comment: In this case `data-key="id"` and you can use `items` from `data` for `data-sources` instead `computedItems`

Comment: In the above example you have `productid` but you can't use it because it is not unique. Based on `docs`, `data-key` require an unique field from item

Comment: Please read the `vue-virtual-scroll-list` documentation for clarity